# How to Remove T00:00:00Z from DateTime in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL. I am using MySQL 5.6.

I have inserted values of DateTime data with DATE_FORMAT(date_add('2020-07-01', interval hours.hour hour).

Hours.hour is just a table with hours 0 - 23 that I am using to populate the database with every hour for a specific date.

However, the data is coming out like this: 2020-07-01T00:00:00Z.

Tried to force it by DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s) but did not work.

Does anyone know how I can remove the 'T' and 'Z' from the DateTime data?

Comment: You'll need the `DATE_FORMAT` call on your select queries, not your inserts.

Comment: If you are new to MySQL, then stop using 5.6, and start using a newer version, like 8. Support for 5.6 end in Feb 2021, and 8.0 and in Apr 2026 ([more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL))

Comment: *However, the data is coming out like this: 2020-07-01T00:00:00Z.* This is absolutely impossible, MySQL cannot return datetime value in this format. This is your client software "service" - so none query edition can help. Solve your problem on the client side and and make the client not convert datetime value received from MySQL.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT returns a string. Are you storing datetime values as strings?